# Should I use a html table or divs for a songlist?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am making an iTunes like interface which will have a list of songs which will be sortable and responsive. My intuition tells me to steer clear of HTML tables but really a table is what I am creating with divs.

I have seen its possible to make [responsive tables](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/).

I'm sure its possible to make the interface with either tables or divs but which is easier? What are the advantages of each technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a HTML Table.

There is nothing wrong with HTML tables, they are designed for tabular data.

---

People are often told to steer clear of tables because they are too often used for layout purposes which isn't semantically correct.

Comment: This question has been hashed out so many times it's not reasonable to expect anyone to do it again.

Answer (score 2):

The demo on the page provided seems like a good option. A table will save you a lot of time in the formatting and floating of divs, though there are a number of options either way.

In terms of what you should do semantically, that's a separate question--this is precisely the kind of situation where tables are appropriate: you're presenting data that is tabular and has predictable categories. Ensure that you have sensible headers and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of semantics. Tables should be used for tabular data, regardless if it's easy or not.